# Problem with WIFI after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, macos

I have problem with WiFi after sleep on my Macbook Pro 13 2015 Sierra. After sleep laptop is still connected to the network but i can't load websites, ping. I must wait long time or turn of and turn on wifi to resolve problem

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook maybe connecting to wrong server while asleep. Check that you are connected to correct Wifi.  I have this problem on my iMac. After waking, the internet was very sluggish if working at all. For some reason my computer switched its connection to another server without a password. I have to manually change it back to my own wifi.